# Vertical alignment of arrays in an array

Tags: vertical-alignment, matrices, arrays

I need to write a matrix with decorations, and I decided to use arrays in an array. I seem to be able to "almost" achieve what I wanted, but there is a couple of questions I would like to ask.

Here is an example and code. There are 4 sub-arrays in an array.

[image]

> Q1 The first two columns and the last two columns are aligned well, but I do not know how to make all of them aligned vertically.

I tried to put overbrace/underbace for the first two, but it did not help.

> Q2 Is there a way to make the separator starting/ending from the first row and the last row, not from the starting and ending point of overbrace/underbrace?

I tried to play with Bigl and Bigr, but I did not succeed.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c|c|cc}
\begin{array}{c}
x
\end{array}
&
\overbrace{
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
* 
\end{array} \right.
}^{f}
&
\overbrace{
\begin{array}{c|c}
\underbrace{
\begin{array}{c}
* 
\end{array}
}_{xx~terms}
&
\left.
\begin{array}{cccc}
0 
\end{array}
\right]
\end{array}
}^{g}
\end{array}
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

I also tried \def\arraystretch{2}, but it did not help.

Comment: Can you draw a picture? I'm not clear what you mean in Q2.

Comment: What about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDOaD.png)?

Comment: @Werner That is very neat. Is it different to Sandy's answer below? If so, I'm interested in seeing your code.

Comment: Use [Sandy's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406818/5764), swap [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) for [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) and use `\mathclap{\text{$xx$ terms}}`.

Comment: @Werner I have no objection to replacing it. Can you explain why such replacement is necessary/recommended?

Comment: @Youngsu: `the $xx$ terms` text unnecessarily pushes out the content represented by `*` since its wider than the `\underbrace` itself. `\mathclap` removes any horizontal width from the `$xx$ terms` description. It's not necessary, but perhaps is aesthetically more pleasing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

[image]

You don't need an array. Just one line of math with over- and under-braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
x|\overbrace{[\;*\;}^f|\overbrace{\underbrace{*}_{xx\text{ terms}}\mid\;0\;]}^g
\]
\end{document}
```

It now occurs to me that you may want the overbraces to be *inside* the delimiters. And I think you want the `*` terms to be potentially bigger (vertically) as in the following:

[image]

The code is more complicated, but all the delimiters will adjust in size. I made a macro for the 3x1 matrix called `\vertm` just to simplify a bit. Then there is a second macro called `\vphnm` that is just the first matrix enclosed in a `\vphantom` command. This is necessary to have the delimiters adjust to the matrix and not to the over and under braces.

Note Werner's suggestion to use `mathtools` and `\mathclap`.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\vertm}{\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix}}
\newcommand{\vphnm}{\vphantom{\vertm}}

\begin{document}
\[
x\left|\vphnm\right[\!\overbrace{\vertm}^f\left|\vphnm\right.%
    \overbrace{\underbrace{\vertm}_{\mathclap{\text{$xx$ terms}}}%
    \left|\vphnm\;0\right.}^g\left.\vphnm\!\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one more question. The entries I have are vertical matrices. So \mid does not extend all the way up and down. Is there a command which does the job? I was thinking of using something like array{:c} (in my work I need : instead of | in the example) in between, but I'd prefer using something that is compact.

Comment: Which entries are the vertical matrices? Does `\Big|` do the job? Do you also want the brackets to adjust in size?

Comment: I do not believe that \Big| extends arbitrary in size. Yes, I want the brackets to adjust in size.

Comment: Please see my updated response. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: It looks very good. The only question I have is if one can replace \left| by something like \left: to have a long enough :. But I believe this can be a separate question. Thank you again for your help!